# How many emails can Google App Script send in a day?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, limit, quota

I'll be deploying a Google Form later on that will cause a traffic of around 1000 submission per day for 2-3 days.

I've researched the quotas and came up with this:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Email recipients per day    100* / day

As for Google Apps:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852

Messages per day    Daily sending limit*    2,000 (500 for trial accounts)

I'm confused whether it's 100 per day or 2000 because maybe the 2000 is for Google Apps and not Google Apps Script.

Will my intentions be possible given these limitations? What exactly are the limitations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can check the status of the service and quotas in the Apps Script menu bar  Help -> Dashboard (quotas)
[image]

So yeah: email recipients per day 100* / day

But here is a better explanation

[image]

[Link for source](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

Cheers